# Dsv3 vs Dsv2 Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am looking at [Azure VM size page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-general) and am trying to understand a few things

1) Why is 's' in Dsv3 small.  Does it mean anything?  v2 series has capital S(DSv2-series).

2) Similarly the the VM's are named as "Standard_D2**s**_v3" where 's' comes after the number, compared to "Standard_DS2_v2" for v2 VM's where 'S' comes before the number and makes a lot more sense.  Is it just a typo?

Comment: Letter "S" means the virtual machine supports SSD based hard drives, i.e. Azure Premium Storage. Casing of "S", does not matter, nor does placement of letter S. There might have been a different naming convention at some point. In my opinion, this is just a typo. Compare e.g. how older A servies VMs were named with an increasing index. Index just meant that A2 is faster than A1. Since the introduction of the F series, the index refers to number of cores. F4 got 4 cores.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

S - premium hdd (ssd). v2\v3 generation.

apparently microsoft things that their naming convention wasnt confusing enough so they decided to change it :)

initially they were called D2\DS2 and now they are D2_v3\D2s_v3